# A Matt Helm-style action novel with killer turtles?

Tags: identification-request

I have vague memories from before the year 2000, of reading a paperback novel, perhaps a serial. It was about a super-spy, detective, or secret agent. It was more in the style of "Matt Helm" than "James Bond."

There is only one scene that I remember. It took place at a large indoor pool. The big baddie had had several female captives tossed into the pool. A gate opened, and large, man-eating turtles were released into the pool. In a very graphic sequence, the turtles chased down, dismembered, and ate the women.

I would appreciate it if anybody knows, or could suggest, the name of this novel. Or the name of the protagonist, or series.

Comment: You state "GIMPS" in caps. Is that an acronym? Emphasis on a rude word for handicapped people? A reference to the open-source drawing program?

Comment: Possibly GIMPS stands for Girl In Mortal Peril Sequence.  That is just a wild guess.

Comment: In my question, GIMP is an acronym for "Girl In Mortal Peril. I intended it to be plural. I will edit the question.

Comment: Google suggests that's not a very well known acronym at all. It's not on TV Tropes either. I know google is not what it was, but given the question doesn't need the term, can I suggest deleting it entirely.

Comment: As "GIMP" is not a common acronym, as well as I wouldn't want to link to any website devoted to the subject, I agree that the question will stand without including the term any further.